# Windows Programming - Loading an Image from C drive With administrator owner

Tags: visual-c++

I want to display a bitmap image from C drive. The owner of this image is Administrator. I am trying to use LoadImage() function to load this image. It is always returning either 0 or 1814 in getlasterror().

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, 
L"C:\\test.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_SHARED);
DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
```

When the last parameter is LR_SHARED, it returns 1814 in getlasterror().
When the last parameter is LR_LOADFROMFILE, it returns 0 in getlasterror().

How will I fix this issue ?

The test.bmp file is generated from another application. Therefore, it's owner is always set to administrator.

Comment: Since you are loading from a file, it should be `LR_LOADFROMFILE`. Why do you want to use `LR_SHARED`?

Comment: When I am using LR_LOADFROMFILE, then also returned value is NULL. But getlasterror() is returning 0.

Comment: Since `GetLastError()` is returning `0`, by any chance, is it problem with `NULL` check?

Comment: HANDLE hBitmap1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, 
                                                       L"c:\\test.bmp",
       IMAGE_BITMAP, 0,0, 
                                                    LR_LOADFROMFILE);
      if (hBitmap1 == NULL)
      {
       DebugPrintLn(GetLastError());
      }  I am getting the output 0 and handle is null